# Small Batch of Mortar

Tags: mortar

I'm looking to patch a couple areas in my basement with type S mortar. I don't need much. Is there a method for mixing small batches of mortar? Either by measurement or feel? I thought I saw somewhere that you want a peanut butter like consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just mix in the same ratio as the original instructions. If the instructions say to mix 2.7L water to 20kg mortar, that's 0.135L per 1kg. So if you only want 5kg mortar, you'd mix 5 * 0.135 = 0.675L water. Same applies if you're mixing with sand or lime.